# Unity3d getting terrain height

Tags: unity, terrain

I am making an RTS game in unity like Total War games. As for rendering I am using Graphics draw mesh instanced method and after culling a I can easily render massive amount of soldiers on battlefield also they are animating with shader. I am not using unity gameobjects or unity physic engine(Also they are costly) as only data I am providing is Matrix4*4 to DrawInstancedIndirect method and rendering.Problem is I want to get height of terrain at specific position(to place unit on terrain) So I can pass Y value to Matrix4*4 for rendering. After seraching documentation I found that there are few ways to get height.

**Terrain.SampleHeight** :
It is easy to get height with this method just need to pass vector position but
costly As When there comes 10,000s of units on battlefield 10k calls for sample height kills performance.

**TerrainData GetHeights** : Can get heightvalue from it in 2d array but height I get is only for int value i.e [10,500] so there is not any option to get value sayif specific unit is at position[10.52,234.8]

**TerrainData.GetInterpolatedHeight** : I can get height for float values but I am getting inconsistant result with it.

One option for me is to make flat terrain but it kills immersion. I ran out of ideas here Is there any way I can get of terrain by either terrain texture or by shader ?
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0NKg.jpg)

EDIT: GetinterpolatedCode

```
         for (int i = 0; i < position.Length; i++)
        {//position is array contains info of all vectors 
         //t is terrainData
            q = t.GetInterpolatedHeight(position[i].x, position[i].z);
            position[i] = new Vector3(position[i].x,q, position[i].z);
            print(position[i]+"//"+ t.GetInterpolatedHeight(position[i].x, position[i].z));
        }
```

Comment: I think your question should be why TerrainData.GetInterpolatedHeight is giving you inconsistent results.  Otherwise this is too broad for anyone to answer completely. I think the answer might be that you're giving it world co-ordinates, not local co-ordinates normalised to 0...1

Comment: @JeffUK Hello there, I am giving local co ordinates to the function. I am not sure why it is happening though maybe while giving position[Vector.x,Vector.z]of any unit there some presicion value error  while converting to float from vector3

Comment: If you could put some code in that demonstrates that issue, that's a question we can have a go at answering